# Münchausen numbers in Prolog, how speed it up?

Tags: prolog, combinatorics

This code gives me some [Münchhausen Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_digit-to-digit_invariant),
unfortunately only using the `0^0 = 0` convention:

```
digits(0, P, Q, R) :- !, P = Q, R = P.
digits(N, P, Q, R) :-
   M is N-1,
   between(0, 9, D),
   S is P*10+D,
   (D = 0 -> T = Q; T is Q+D^D),
   digits(M, S, T, R).
```

I get the following result in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- digits(4, 0, 0, R).
R = 0 ;
R = 1 ;
R = 3435 ;
false.
```

The above searches the interval `[0,10^4-1]`. How
could I search the interval `[0,10^10-1]` in short time?

**Edit 13.03.2023:**
According to this paper, we can settle the question whether
there are other Münchhausen numbers once and forall.

> **On a curious property of 3435**
> Daan van Berkel - 2009
> https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.3038

Thats quite amazing and it works since there are only
finitely many Münchenhausen numbers.

Comment: Does this not *work* for N>4, or is it just too slow when N>4?

Comment: If you are so concerned about performance, why are you using Prolog?

Comment: More concerned with an algorithmic speed-up than with Prolog performance.

Answer (score 1):

Using interval arithmetic we can speed-up the search.
The new definition digits2/4 is found as an appendix
to this post. It already shows a speed-up for `N=4`:

```
?- time((between(1,100,_), digits(4, 0, 0, R), fail; true)).
% 4,333,101 inferences, 0.516 CPU in 0.506 seconds (102% CPU, 8403590 Lips)
true.

?- time((between(1,100,_), digits2(4, 0, 0, R), fail; true)).
% 958,101 inferences, 0.141 CPU in 0.146 seconds (96% CPU, 6813163 Lips)
true.
```

The speed-up is enough to solve `N=10` in around 5 minutes.

```
?- time((digits2(10, 0, 0, R), write(R), nl, fail; true)).
0
1
3435
438579088
% 2,211,759,677 inferences, 311.531 CPU in 312.360 seconds
(100% CPU, 7099640 Lips)
true.
```

As also mentioned on Wikipedia, the new number is indeed
Münchhausen under the `0^0 = 0` convention:

```
?- X is 4^4+3^3+8^8+5^5+7^7+9^9+8^8+8^8.
X = 438579088.
```

**Code with Explanation:**
The intervals are computed as `[S*10^M,S*10^M+10^M-1`] and
`[T,T+M*9^9]`. They give the range of possible values for the
final P and Q. Since the search terminates with `P = Q`,

the search can only terminate if the intervals are not
disjoint. The `(=<)/2` comparisons check whether this is
the case and only continue if the check is positive:

```
digits2(0, P, Q, R) :- !, P = Q, R = P.
digits2(N, P, Q, R) :-
    M is N-1,
    H is 10^M,
    between(0, 9, D),
    S is P*10+D,
    (D = 0 -> T = Q; T is Q+D^D),
    S*H =< T+M*387420489,
    T =< S*H+H-1,
    digits2(M, S, T, R).
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could we search N=10 in less than 5 minutes?

I can get close; the nine digit answer in ~3 min 45 seconds, but it takes another 4 min 35 seconds to exhaust the search space and stop.

- The code uses CLPFD.
- I inlined the equations for a number from the sum of its digits for each length, because writing a recursive predicate which counts out the length and picks off the digits into a reversed list is much slower.
- CLPFD does `0^0=1` so the int_pow makes a special case to handle `0^0=0`, otherwise there is no larger answer.
- The split of DFirst, DRest and PFirst, PRest is so it doesn't come out with leading zeros like `[0,0,3,4,3,5]`. NB. because of that blocking the first digit from being zero this code doesn't find 0 as an answer.

```
digits_int([Int], Int).
digits_int([B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([E,D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (E * 10^4) + (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([F,E,D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (F * 10^5) + (E * 10^4) + (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([G,F,E,D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (G * 10^6) + (F * 10^5) + (E * 10^4) + (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (H * 10^7) + (G * 10^6) + (F * 10^5) + (E * 10^4) + (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.
digits_int([I,H,G,F,E,D,C,B,A], Int) :-
    Int #= (I * 10^8) + (H * 10^7) + (G * 10^6) + (F * 10^5) + (E * 10^4) + (D * 1000) + (C * 100) + (B * 10) + A.

% Int raised to the power of itself.
int_pow(Int, Pow) :-
    zcompare(Order, Int, 0),
    int_pow(Order, Int, Pow).

int_pow(=, 0, 0).
int_pow(>, Int, Pow) :-
    Pow #= Int^Int.

munch(Number, Len, Digits, Powers) :-
    length(Digits, Len),

    same_length(Digits, Powers),
    Digits = [DFirst|DRest],
    DFirst in 1..9,
    DRest ins 0..9,

    Powers = [PFirst|PRest],
    PFirst in       1 \/ 4 \/ 27 \/ 256 \/ 3125 \/ 46656 \/ 823543 \/ 16777216 \/ 387420489,
    PRest  ins 0 \/ 1 \/ 4 \/ 27 \/ 256 \/ 3125 \/ 46656 \/ 823543 \/ 16777216 \/ 387420489,

    maplist(int_pow, Digits, Powers),

    sum(Powers, #=, Number),
    digits_int(Digits, Number).
```

and query example:

```
?- between(0,9,Len),
   format('Searching length ~w...~n', [Len]),
   time((munch(Number, Len, Digits, Powers),
        flatten([Digits, Powers, Number], _Vars),
        labeling([enum], _Vars))).

Searching length 0...
% 7 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

Searching length 1...
% 1,963 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.006 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
Len = Number, Number = 1,
Digits = Powers, Powers = [1] ;
% 79 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

Searching length 2...
% 7,890 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.015 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

Searching length 3...
% 27,237 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.015 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

Searching length 4...
% 81,902 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.017 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)
Len = 4,
Number = 3435,
Digits = [3, 4, 3, 5],
Powers = [27, 256, 27, 3125] ;
% 13,469 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.004 seconds (0% CPU, Infinite Lips)

Searching length 5...
% 308,551 inferences, 0.047 CPU in 0.064 seconds (74% CPU, 6582421 Lips)

Searching length 6...
% 572,259 inferences, 0.078 CPU in 0.075 seconds (104% CPU, 7324915 Lips)

Searching length 7...
% 6,538,419 inferences, 0.781 CPU in 0.783 seconds (100% CPU, 8369176 Lips)

Searching length 8...
% 139,216,538 inferences, 16.203 CPU in 16.368 seconds (99% CPU, 8591956 Lips)

Searching length 9...
% 1,904,571,608 inferences, 220.891 CPU in 224.342 seconds (98% CPU, 8622238 Lips)
Len = 9,
Number = 438579088,
Digits = [4, 3, 8, 5, 7, 9, 0, 8, 8],
Powers = [256, 27, 16777216, 3125, 823543, 387420489, 0, 16777216, 16777216] ;
% 2,249,925,126 inferences, 266.766 CPU in 275.632 seconds (97% CPU, 8434089 Lips)
false.
```

NB. `labeling([enum]` is important, the other search strategies perform much worse. I did try inlining the digit multipliers such as changing `10^6` to `1000000`, and that slowed it down.

> More concerned with an algorithmic speed-up than with Prolog performance.

(I worked on this before you commented that).

Comment: "It is sad you didn't comment that" ~~> According to "Blum's speedup theorem" you can speedup any algorithm somehow, like with more memory and caching. But interestingly some CLP(FD) inspired reasoning does wonders. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum%27s_speedup_theorem

Answer (score 1):

I get a faster method with Prolog first argument indexing:

```
?- time((canonball, munchhausen(_), fail; true)).
% 4,633,344 inferences, 0.594 CPU in 0.589 seconds (101% CPU, 7803527 Lips)
true.

?- munchhausen(R).
R = 0 ;
R = 1 ;
R = 3435 ;
R = 438579088 ;
false.
```

The code is based on the observation that the fixpoint
equation for a split number `m*10^k + n` can be reordered
so that `m` is on one side and `n` is on the other side:

```
m*10^k - F(m) = F(n) - n
```

The rest is tabulating `F(n) - n`:

```
canonball :-
   retractall(cache(_,_)),
   between(0, 99999, N), map(N, Y), C is Y-N,
   assertz(cache(C, N)), fail; true.

munchhausen(R) :-
   between(0, 99999, M), map(M, X), B is 100000*M-X,
   cache(B, N), R is 100000*M+N.

map(0, X) :- !, X = 0.
map(N, X) :-
   M is N//10,
   map(M, Y),
   D is N mod 10,
   (D = 0 -> X=Y; X is Y+D^D).
```